# svn log missing revisions

Tags: linux, svn

I appear to be missing revisions. I wrote

```
> svn commit -m "blah. go back"
Sending        report/report2.pl
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 6.

> svn info
Path: .
URL: file:///home/MYNAME/svn_repository
Repository Root: file:///home/MYNAME/svn_repository
Repository UUID: 05a62b19-7276-0410-ba54-59ad643a30b7
Revision: 3
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: MYNAME
Last Changed Rev: 3
Last Changed Date: 2009-10-21 09:52:02 -0400 (Wed, 21 Oct 2009)
```

huh... I thought i was on revision 6.

My revisions still seem to be there if i try to merge to an older version

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SVN does not automatically update your entire working tree to the latest revision.

In your case, you committed a file in directory `./report`, but then asked for info on `.`. If you'd asked for info on `./report` you should see revision 6.

If this disturbs you, run `svn update` after every commit (if you're in a multi-person team, you should be doing it before every build anyway).